# Oracle Forms auto query

Tags: forms, oracle

I'm using Oracle Forms and I'm trying to auto-query data when a new form opens (that is, automatically generating `SELECT * from TABLE` data without clicking on "Execute Query" button from DEFAULT&SMARTBAR menu).

How can I automatically execute query when the new form opens without clicking on the <kbd>Execute Query</kbd> button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE trigger with code like:

```
go_block('BLOCK1');
do_key('execute_query');
```

Comment: I can't use that because I have forms with two data blocks (a master-detail relationship).

Comment: Use DO_KEY (see amended answer) then this will do exactly what pressing the Execute Query button would do on that block - e.g. coordinate querying master and details.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works well. That is, if I run the form with the trigger. If I click on a menu item from my main form and go to the form with the trigger, nothing happens.

Comment: How are you calling the form from the main form?

Comment: Put the same code in When-Window-Activated trigger. When you calling form from another form WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE trigger will not work.

Comment: WHEN-WINDOW-ACTIVATED will run every time the focus move to this window. If you requery the block in this trigger, the current position will be lost and your pointer go to the first queried record.